# A way to parse multidimensional string array to list c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

If need an simple way to parse this string:

```
string a = "[[[
[-118.407, 33.749],
[-118.407, 33.749],
[-118.407, 33.749],
[-118.407, 33.749],
[-118.407,33.749]
]]]"
```

to something like: `List<List<List<List<double>>>>`

Comment: I think you have  json string. It certainly is not a string array.

Comment: Trying to read/store data for a multipolygon representation (GeoJson) in a single variable

Comment: Tried successfully this: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<double>>("[-76.967172, 50,-76.967172, 50]") for a non-nested string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use your code fragments diectly with the right method:

```
var r = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize< List<List<List<List<double>>>> >(a);
```

`System.Text.Json` is the new .net Core serializer, for older platforms use Newtonsoft:

```
var r = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< List<List<List<List<double>>>> >(a);
```

But I think you may have 1 level of  `List<>` too many. Experiment.

Comment: Maybe, I just noticed that the outer list has Count==1. Maybe there is 1 `[]` too much as well.